# spaces in a text

Tags: customization

I try to insert spaces in a curriculum vitae, but this does not work. Everything continues to run one after the other. See: www.barbarahaveman.net under biography. Thank you for your help, Barbara

Comment: You should ask WordPress.com support if you need help with their editor.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the space between the paragraphs? If so, the reason why there is no space is that they are **divs**, not **paragraphs**. The code for each is `<div id="long id number unique for this paragraph and probably generated by the theme">`. While paragraphs have set spaces defined in the theme, divs do not.

There are many ways to fix this, including figuring out why they are divs and not paragraphs.

Depending on what you want to do and your knowledge of css, I propose 3 ways to fix it just for this page.

1- In the window to edit the text for that page, go in the Text tab in the top right to see the actual code. See if you can change all the `<div id=` to `<p id=` and the corresponding closing tags from `</div>` to `</p>`. If so, that will apply the regular styles from the theme for paragraphs.

2- You can also make them paragraphs within the divs. To do that just add `<p>` at the beginning and `</p>` at the end of each paragraph.

3- If that doesn't work, you can apply styles just for that page. Find where in your theme you can add custom css (usually under Theme Options) and add the following:

.page-id-4 .entry-content div {
    margin: 0 0 1.8em;
}

This will add the exact same margin below every div in that block of text than what the paragraphs are set to on the rest of the site.

P.S.: Please note that these are punctual fixes; they address the problem that you mentionned specifically for that page, not for the entire theme, which would require a more in-depth analysis. For example, the entire block of text is in a div within a div within a div, all with the same css classes: `<div class="t pg-1m0 pg-1x3 pg-1h4 pg-1y1e pg-1ff2 pg-1fs1 pg-1fc0 pg-1sc0 pg-1ls0 pg-1ws0">`. Although it is strange, in the end it will not create any issues.

This takes care the effect, not the cause. If you just wanted to fix it quickly, these solutions solutions are fine.